# Replication not working on DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, domain-controller, windows-server-2012-r2, replication

I am getting the following error (4612) on my secondary and tertiary DCs:

```
The DFS Replication service initialized SYSVOL at local path C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain and is waiting to perform initial replication. The replicated folder will remain in the initial synchronization state until it has replicated with its partner VIEW-A.ea-hq.com. 
If the server was in the process of being promoted to a domain controller, the domain controller will not advertise and function as a domain controller until this issue is resolved.
This can occur if the specified partner is also in the initial synchronization state, or if sharing violations are encountered on this server or the sync partner.
If this event occurred during the migration of SYSVOL from File Replication service (FRS) to DFS Replication, changes will not replicate out until this issue is resolved. This can cause the SYSVOL folder on this server to become out of sync with other domain controllers. 

Additional Information: 
Replicated Folder Name: SYSVOL Share 
Replicated Folder ID: 7706C7EB-D963-4D9D-9E71-42714B264668 
Replication Group Name: Domain System Volume 
Replication Group ID: A12B3A85-9A29-4851-BEA2-896BFC26AB90 
Member ID: 9C343104-F159-4198-8F31-CF62CF53E6D7 
Read-Only: 0
```

I am also getting (5002):

```
The DFS Replication service encountered an error communicating with partner VIEW-A for replication group Domain System Volume. 

Partner DNS address: VIEW-A.ea-hq.com 

Optional data if available: 
Partner WINS Address: VIEW-A 
Partner IP Address: 10.0.0.21 

The service will retry the connection periodically. 

Additional Information: 
Error: 1753 (There are no more endpoints available from the endpoint mapper.) 
Connection ID: A12B3A85-9A29-4851-BEA2-896BFC26AB90 
Replication Group ID: 752FFA5C-36B1-4335-B2E9-9F1972037215
```

How do I fix this? Should I just take the primary DC offline (view-a) and rebuild it?

Comment: Do you have other DC's that you can check against, and see which one is the source?

Comment: @Davidw My other DCs report the same error about that DC.

Comment: Are basic communications(i.e. ping) with it functional? And can you connect to the sysvol share?

Comment: @Davidw Ping works. How can I test the sysvol share?

Comment: Just try navigating to it via any file browser on another DC via \\dc fqdn\sysvol (as an example), so it would be \\view-a.ea-hq.com\sysvol.

Comment: Also, when you pinged, did you use the host name/fqdn, or ip address?

Comment: @Davidw I am able to ping both the FQDN and IP address.

Comment: @Davidw Also I can navigate to the share.

Comment: Use your google fu "1753 no more endpoints". There are several hits with very lengthy articles for troubleshooting this kind of error on microsoft.com

Comment: Based on the error message, it sounds you have a port exhaustion. Using "netstat" command to check if you have any free port left, and what app is consuming ports.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the a similar set of errors recently when my primary DC's system volume filled up (I'd just taken the job, and the DC was previously sitting at less than a gig of HD space and I hadn't gotten around to freeing space). When it happened, the nt file replication system (ntfrs) on the PDC got corrupted. Make sure that the structure of the sysvol folder on all DCs mimics the folder structure outlined here [Here](http://mantushaw.blogspot.com/2013/02/sysvol-folder-structure.html). If any of the DCs do not match that folder structure, you may need to shut down the DFS replication service and correct the folder structure and then restart it. Unfortunately, my issues resolved around the ntfrs not the DFS replication service. Here's to hoping the same fix might work for you though.